# Authenticate twitter to get json feed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I'm running into "rate limit exceeded" issues on my app. I want to get a feed:

```
http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/bbcnews.json
```

But it tells me that the rate limit is exceeded. I assume this means for all users of the app combined. How would I authenticate my twitter app (which I have set up with twitter) before requesting this feed, or incorporate the authentication in the feed request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per twitter's documentation:

"Unauthenticated calls are permitted 150 requests per hour. Unauthenticated calls are measured against the public facing IP of the server or device making the request."

So, for a mobile device, this limit would be at a per device basis, not overall.

If you would like an authenticated call, you will have to let user user go through oauth authentication and store the token on the device for subsequent calls. There are various sample projects on github & the rest of the web that would help you down this road.